# Correct old paths over entire app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, regex, asset-pipeline, replace

I just updated an outdated app to the pipeline, and 90% of my css paths are hosed.  The old path was: **/images/scrollers/upcoming_left.png** the new path is **/assets/scrollers/upcoming_left.png**

Simply put, the first /images needs to become /assets across the entire app.

I was thinking of doing a find and replace across the entire stylesheets directory to take /images and change it to /assets .

The problem is, I only want to replace paths that start /images, not paths like http://foobar.com/images or /assets/images/foobar.png.

My regex skills are lacking but i'm pretty sure there's a dryer solution for this.  I'm running rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3, with sublime text 2...any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: Sublime Text uses [boost regex syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), you might try `\B/images`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do a fine and replace on `("/images`? I'm guessing that all your css paths are something like `url("/images/....")`

Comment: I ended up doing this before I saw your reply.  I searched the stylesheets directory for three find and replaces, 1. url("/images/") 2.url("/images/') 3. url(/images/)  -- pretty sketchy commit ;-)